# Why do you pass LayoutInflater to inflate()?

Tags: android, android-inflate

Here's the code:

```
private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.**inflate(layoutInflater)**
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
}
```

Why layoutInflater? Isn't `inflate` supposed to inflate an xml file?

Doing a Ctr+Q on `inflate` gives this `public static @NonNull com.example.ActivityMainBinding inflate(@NonNull android.view.LayoutInflater inflater)`
I can't find this function on the android developer website. It's either in LayoutInflater or View. Where can you find this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't inflate supposed to inflate an xml file?

Yes. A `LayoutInflater` inflates layout resources.

> I can't find this function on the android developer website

It is code-generated in your project. That generated code is not significantly different than if you had typed it in yourself, which is why it uses a `LayoutInflater` to inflate the associated layout resource.

> Where can you find this function?

On your computer. Specifically, it will be in one of the subdirectories off of your module's `build/` directory.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know they put a lot of code in those .java files.